# Looping through pages using PyQt4 and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pyqt

I'm trying to extract some data from a multiple pages in a website with content generated with Javascript. 
So I'm using PyQt4 to and Beautiful Soup to loop through pages and extract some data fields.

```
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage


class Client(QWebPage):

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_page_load)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def on_page_load(self):
        self.app.quit()

products_titles = []
urls= ['url1', 'url2', 'url3']

for url in urls: 
   print "Parsing URL: " + url + '\n'
   client_response = Client(url)
   source = client_response.mainFrame().toHtml()
   soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
   print get_product_category(soup)
```

But when I run it crushes and gives this error:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::configurationAdded(QNetworkConfiguration) to QNetworkConfigurationManager::configurationAdded(QNetworkConfiguration)
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::configurationRemoved(QNetworkConfiguration) to QNetworkConfigurationManager::configurationRemoved(QNetworkConfiguration)
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::configurationChanged(QNetworkConfiguration) to QNetworkConfigurationManager::configurationChanged(QNetworkConfiguration)
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::onlineStateChanged(bool) to QNetworkConfigurationManager::onlineStateChanged(bool)
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::configurationUpdateComplete() to QNetworkConfigurationManager::updateCompleted()
[1]    14809 segmentation fault  python products.py
```

I don't know what I'm I'm doing wrong, Please help if you know what going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would send in a list of URLs and have a single instance of your QApplication load them sequentially rather than instantianting and destroying a bunch of QApplications.

In other words try something more like this...

```
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl, pyqtSignal
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage

class Client(QWebPage):

    new_url = pyqtSignal(['QString'], name='new_url')

    def __init__(self, urls):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.urls = urls
        self.pages = dict()
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.new_url.connect(self.load_url)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_page_load)
        if len(self.urls):
            self.new_url.emit(urls.pop())
        self.app.exec_()

    def load_url(self, url):
        self.current_url = url
        print "Loading: {0}".format(url)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))

    def on_page_load(self):
        print "Retrieved: {0}".format(self.current_url)
        self.pages[self.current_url] = unicode(self.mainFrame().toHtml())
        if len(self.urls):
            self.new_url.emit(self.urls.pop())
        else:
            self.app.quit()

urls= ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.yahoo.com', 'http://www.bing.com']

client = Client(urls)
for (url, page) in client.pages.items():
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
    print "{0}\t{1}".format(url, soup.title.text)
```

Reinstantiating a bunch of QApplications seems like a really bad idea and I can understand a segmentation fault in that context.  The network errors prior to the segmentation fault seem a bit odd to me though.  Give the above a try and see if you have any better luck with it.  It's working fine for me.

Comment: Thank you it is working just fine and way faster than my solution !!